# DialogFragment timepicker onCancel and onDismiss problem

Tags: java, android, datepicker, timepicker

I've tried to implement a Time Picker which is opened up by a SwitchCompat, so when I enable the option, the Time Picker shows up, it works fine but if I press cancel, or back button or simply press outside of the time picker, the Switch stays at the ON position and I want it to get back to OFF when I don't choose the time in Time Picker. Thought that maybe onCancel method could help but it does not, or simply I made some mistake with implementing it, there's the related code:

```java
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener, TimePickerDialog.OnDismissListener, TimePickerDialog.OnCancelListener {
    private EditText textLastHour;
    private KeyListener keyListener;
    private SwitchCompat hourSwitch;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        textLastHour = findViewById(R.id.finalHourText);
        textLastHour.setKeyListener(null);
        textLastHour.setHint("Option not selected");

        hourSwitch = findViewById(R.id.switch_hour);

        hourSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                    timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");

                } else {
                    textLastHour.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        textLastHour = findViewById(R.id.finalHourText);
        textLastHour.setText("Final alarm at: " + hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        hourSwitch.setChecked(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        hourSwitch.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

I've tried both `onDismiss` and `onCancel` and neither have worked here, is there any solution to make the Switch go back to the original position if you cancel the Time Picker? Added the `DatePicker` to tags as I feel like it may have the same solution as `TimePicker` for that problem.

My `TimePickerFragment` Class:

```java
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I saw you don't have a callback on cancel/dismiss when the user not set the time. I would suggest to create another class that will inherit from TimePickerDialog and create anther callback when the dialog is dismissed

Comment: I will add my TimePickerClass in a sec here, and yeah, I have the issue with these methods but kinda don't understand how to fix them, found those onCancel and onDismiss listeners on the internet, but none of the solutions work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually simpler than I thought all you need to do is to add a dismiss listener and change your ui/logic accordingly

```java
TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    }
}, 10, 10, true);

dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "dismissed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

dialog.show();
```

You can use the standard TimePickerDialog

Edit: Put everything to `onCreate()` except for `dialog.show()`, `dialog.show()` goes into the ifChecked in the Switch

Comment: Where should I add your code? I kinda don't understand it. Should it be in the if(ifChecked) ?

Comment: Correct, if you want to open your dialog only when the user turned on the switch/checkbox, the code needs to be there

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot, just had to change the onDismissListener to onCancelListener because onDismissListener launches even after i've tried to set the time

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your code you haven't defined any listener in your TimePickerFragment  class. you can add following code in your TimePickerFragment :

```
public  class TimePickerFragment(Context context) extends DialogFragment{

    interface OnCompleteListener {
        abstract void onComplete(boolean suceeded);
    }

    OnCompleteListener listener;

    /**

    * your other lines of code

    **/
}
```

Don't forget to set context argument for your class !
Then override onAttach function and inside that implement your listener like this :

```
try {
            this.listener = (OnCompleteListener) context;

        } catch (ClassCastException e) {

            throw ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnCompleteListener");

        }
```

After this in your override onDismiss() and set `listener.onComplete(false);` inside that. And whenever the TimePickerFragment wanted to finish successfully just set `listener.onComplete(true);`

Now we shall back to MainActivity. First of all make MainActivity implement `TimePickerFragment.OnCompleteListener`.

Now you need to override the abstract function of your `OnCompleteListener`. Simply if the argument was false it means that dialog dismissed unsuccessfully, so with a simple if condition set your `Switch` to off programmatically.


Hope I could help.

Comment: the (Context context) creates an error in the class

Comment: @PatrykLipka I've migrated from Kotlin to java so maybe that need a little change but when you added this parameter you should pass your activity when you're instantiating your TimePickerFragment like this in your MainActivity `TimePickerFragment dialog = new TimePickerFragment(this);`